# MySQL exclude customer from query result

Tags: mysql

I have these 2 tables in MySQL

[image: Customers table]

[image: Products table]

Objective: If John Doe has already bought Life Insurance, which in this example he has, he should be excluded from the query result. I have this query but for obvious reasons John Doe is still listed as one of the customers as he has also purchased Medical Aid & Funeral Cover. I cannot add the 2 additional products mentioned to my WHERE clause as well as this will defeat our objective, which is, if we select to exclude clients we have sold Life insurance to, it should only exclude these specific clients

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         dwc.CustomerID,
         dwc.ImportDate,
         dwc.FirstName,
         dwc.LastName,
         dwc.RSAID,
         dwc.PrimaryPhoneNumber,
         TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, dwc.DateOfBirth, CURDATE() ) AS Age,
         dwp.SubmitProduct,
         dwp.EntryDate AS ProductPurchaseDate 
      FROM
         Customers dwc 
         LEFT JOIN
            Products dwp 
            ON dwp.CustomerID = dwc.CustomerID 
   )
   t1 
WHERE
   SubmitProduct != 'Life Insurance' 
GROUP BY
   CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives one row per product per customer (excluding those with Life Insurance)

```
SELECT  c...,
        p...
    FROM Customers AS c
    JOIN Products AS p  ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
            FROM Customers
            WHERE CustomerID = c.CustomerID
              AND ProductSold = 'Life Insurance' )
```

This gives one row per customer (excluding those with Life Insurance) and lists the ProductSolds in a commalist.

```
SELECT  c...,   -- but nothing from `p`
        GROUP_CONCAT(ProductSold) as Products
    FROM Customers AS c
    JOIN Products AS p  ON p.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    GROUP BY c.CustomerID
    HAVING NOT FIND_IN_SET('Life Insurance', Products)
```

Yet another formulation would involve a 3-way JOIN, one of which is a LEFT JOIN with `IS NULL`.  (But that is probably slower and more complex.)